# How to get RGB components of a custom color in ios

Tags: iphone, ios, uicolor, color-scheme, color-picker

I would like to set custom color  programmatically using the method
`[UIColor colorWithRed:(CGFloat)red green:(CGFloat)green blue:(CGFloat)blue alpha:(CGFloat)alpha];`
For which i need to know the value of RBG components.
**I would like to know is there any way by which i can get the RBG components of a custom color so that i can use them in the above mentioned method.**

Answer (score 35, accepted):

You can use the DigitalColor Meter.app included with every Mac OS X install. You can find it in `~/Applications/Utilities/DigitalColor Meter.app`. Use it to inspect the RGB values of any pixel you mouse over. Once you have the values, you just need to divide them by `255.0` because `+colorWithRed:green:blue:alpha:` is expecting a floating point value between 0 and 1.

```
[UIColor colorWithRed:83.0f/255.0f green:217.0f/255.0f blue:58.0f/255.0f alpha:1.0f];
```

Answer (score 9):

You can use Xcode itself to get RGB value of custom color:

Click the arrow for the Color box and in the resulting dialog box choose others. 
[image]

And then you can use RGB Slider option to get RGB values

[image]

Answer (score 2):

To match a color exactly, there is a great utility called "DigitalColor Meter" located in Applications/Utilities/ that can get the RGB for anything on your screen. Take a screen shot of the color you want to replicate, then use this tool to get the information.

Answer (score 2):

Actually there is **no need** for using DigitalColor Meter instead we can use the small **Search Icon**  **[image: search icon]** on color picker in the Interface Builder with which we can exactly adjust the color that we like.It is also possible to look up the color values using RBG scales available in it.